# Passport login works, but incorrect password just times out

Tags: javascript, authentication, passport.js, bcrypt

I am making an auth section on my website. I am using bcrypt-nodejs, passport, and passport-http for authentication and Sql Server and Sequelize for my database. I have made a login route and if I enter the correct password and email then the login is successful and returns the correct user object, but if the wrong username/password is entered or there is an error then it times out.

What I mean is that if I enter a bad password, I can console.log `err` and it shows the correct error, but nothing inside of the `if (err) {}` is reached, and the same thing happens if I enter an email that isn't in the db, passport returns `undefined` for `user` but nothing inside of `if (!user) {}` is ever reached. However, if I enter the correct username and password then it does reach `if (user) {}` and calls `res.json({msg: 'authenticated as ', userEmail});` and the information for userEmail is correct.

Here is what my route looks like:

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('basic', function(err, user, info) {
    console.log(clc.blueBright('err ::::::  '), err);
    var userEmail = user.dataValues.password;
    if (err) {
      res.json({
        msg: 'internal server error'
      });
    }
    if (!user) {
      console.log(clc.redBright('!user ::::::  '));
      res.json({
        msg: 'invalid username or password'
      });
    }
    if (user) {
      res.json({
        msg: 'authenticated as ',
        userEmail
      });

    }
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

My passport_strat looks like this:

```
'use strict';

var Basic = require('passport-http').BasicStrategy;
var User = require('../models/User');
var clc = require('cli-color');

module.exports = function(passport) {
  passport.use('basic', new Basic({}, function(email, password, done) {
    User.findOne({
        where: {
          email: email
        }
      })
      .then(function(user) {
        // console.log(clc.greenBright('Done Callback ::::   '), done);
        if (!user) {
          return done('no such user');
        }
        if (!user.$modelOptions.instanceMethods.verifyPassword(password, user.dataValues.password)) {
          return done('wrong password');
        }
        if (user.$modelOptions.instanceMethods.verifyPassword(password, user.dataValues.password)) {
          // console.log(clc.blueBright('password matched'));
          return done(null, user);
        }
      })
      .error(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
          msg: 'there was a problem logging in to your account'
        });
      })
  }));
}
```

And my User model looks like this:

```
var User = module.exports = sql.define('User', {
  userName: Sql.STRING,
  password: Sql.STRING,
  email: Sql.STRING,
}, {
  instanceMethods: {
    verifyPassword: function(password, userPassword) {
      return bcrypt.compareSync(password, userPassword);
    },
    generateToken: function(secret, callback) {
      return eat.encode({
        id: this.id
      }, secret, callback);
    },
    generateHash: function(password) {
      return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
    }

  }

});
```

I worked on this for hours yesterday and I am stumped. Please let me know if you need any more info. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the answer was simple of course...I was declaring `var userEmail = user.dataValues.password;` at the beginning of my route, so when there was no user object, the function crashed at this point, but it was after the console.log so it logged the `err`. @Datsick also pointed me in the right direction, when I also realized that after fixing the console.log issue, I received the same error no matter what the reason for the failure.

In the end, the working auth looks like this:

passport_strat.js:

```js
'use strict';

var Basic = require('passport-http').BasicStrategy;
var User = require('../models/User');
var clc = require('cli-color');

module.exports = function(passport) {
  passport.use('basic', new Basic({}, function(email, password, done) {
    User.findOne({
        where: {
          email: email
        }
      })
      .then(function(user) {
        if (user) {
          var verified = user.$modelOptions.instanceMethods.verifyPassword(password, user.dataValues.password);
        }
        if (!user) {
          done('no such user');
        }
        if (user && !verified) {
          done('wrong password');
        }
        if (user && verified) {
          done(null, user);
        }
      })
      .error(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
          msg: 'there was a problem logging in to your account'
        });
        done(err);
      })
  }));
}
```

And my route looks like this (the model didn't change):

```js
  app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('basic', {
      session: false
    }, function(err, user, info) {
      if (err && user) {
        console.log(clc.redBright('Login error: '), err);
        res.json({
          msg: 'internal server error'
        });
      }
      // if user is not found due to wrong username or password
      if (err && !user) {
        console.log(clc.redBright('Login error: '), err);
        res.json({
          msg: 'invalid username or password'
        });
      }
      if (user && !err) {
        var userEmail = user.dataValues.email;
        res.json({
          msg: 'authenticated as ',
          userEmail
        });

      }
    })(req, res, next);
  });
```

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try returning your `res.json`

`return res.json`

If there is an error, your if statement will try to send a response, then it falls down to `!user` which if there was an error, I'm sure is also true so it's trying to send multiple headers which is probably what is screwing you up.